# Feature combination/joint features in supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

While trying to come up with appropriate features for a supervised learning problem I had the following idea and wondered if it makes sense and if so, how to algorithmically formulate it.

In an image I want to classify two regions, i.e. two "types" of pixels. Say I have some bounded structure, let's take a circle, and I know I can limit my search space to this circle. Within that circle I want to find a segmenting contour, i.e. a contour that separates my pixels into an inner class A and an outer class B.

I want to implement the following **model**:

*I know that pixels close to the bounding circle are more likely to be in the outer class B.*

Of course, I can use the distance from the bounding circle as a feature, then the algorithm would learn the average distance of the inner contour from the bounding circle.

But: I wonder if I can exploit my model assumption in a smarter way. One heuristic idea would be to weigh other features by this distance, so to say, if a pixel further away from the bounding circle wants to belong to the outer class B, it has to have strongly convincing other features.

This leads to a **general question**:

How can one exploit joint information of features, that were prior individually learned by the algorithm?

And to a **specific question**:

In my outlined setup, does my heuristic idea make sense? At what point of the algorithm should this information be used? What would be recommended literature or what would be buzzwords if I wanted to search for similar ideas in the literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This leads to a general question:
>
> How can one exploit joint information of features, that were prior individually learned by the algorithm?

It is not really clear what you are really asking here. What do you mean by "individually learned by the algorithm" and what would be "joiint information"? First of all, problem is too broad, there is no such tring as "generic supervised learning model", each of them works in at least slightly different way, most falling into three classes:

- Building a regression model of some kind, to map input data to the output and then agregate results for classification (linear regression, artificial neural networks)
- Building geometrical separation of data (like support vector machines, classification-soms' etc.)
- Directly (more or less) estimating probability of given classes (like Naive Bayes, classification restricted boltzmann machines etc.)

in each of them, there is somehow encoded "joint information" regarding features - the classification function is their joint information. In some cases it is easy do interpret (linear regression) and in some it is almost impossible (deep boltzmann machines, generally all deep architectures).

> And to a specific question:
>
> In my outlined setup, does my heuristic idea make sense? At what point of the algorithm should this information be used? What would be recommended literature or what would be buzzwords if I wanted to search for similar ideas in the literature?

To my best knowledge this concept is quite doubtfull. Many models tends to learn and work better, if your data is uncorrelated, while you are trying to do the opposite - correlate everything with some particular feature. This leads to one main concern - why are you doing this? To force model to use mainly this feature?

- If it is so important - maybe a supervised learning is not the good idea, maybe you can directly **model** your problem by appling set of simple rules based on this particular feature?
- If you know the feature is important, but you are aware that in some cases other things matter, and you cannot model them, then your problem will be **how much** to weight your feature. Should it be just `distance*other_feature`? Why not `sqrt(distance)*feature`? What about `log(distance)*feature`? There are countless possibilities, and seek for the best weighting scheme may be much more costfull, then finding a better machine learning model, which can learn your data from its **raw** features.
- If you only **suspect** the importance of the feature, the best possible option would be to... do not trust this belief. Numerous studies have shown, that machine learning models are better in selecting features then humans. In fact, this is the whole point of non-linear models.

In literature, problem they you are trying to solve is generally refered as **incorporating expert knowledge** into the learning process. There are thousands of examples, where there is some kind of knowledge that cannot be directly encoded in data representation, yet too valuable to omit it. You should research terms like "machine learning expert knowledge", and its possible synomyms.

Comment: Thank you for your long answer. I am actually looking for something along the lines as written in the second point of the second half, i.e. weighting a feature by a distance function. My problem then is: if have the algorithm train on some (feature) and then let it decide for a value (distance)*(feature) I think I would screw up the idea of machine learning. On the other hand, learning (distance)*(feature) would yield less information than learning distance and feature individually. Is there a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly - you are considering learning of one feature and then using other? This is for sure simply wrong. Learning two features separately gives more information, but the problem is here in an expert knowledge - this "loss" can be helpful, if your new feature is really much better then those separate ones, but it is a matter of quality, certainty. This is not a kind of decision one can make without dozens of tests and data analysis, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fair amount of work treating the kind of problem you're looking at (which is called segmentation) as an optimisation to be performed on a [Markov Random Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field), which can be solved by graph theoretic methods like GraphCut. Some examples are the work of Pushmeet Kohli at Microsoft Research (try [this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/pkohli/papers/lrkt_eccv2010.pdf) paper).

What you describe is, in that framework, a prior on node membership, where p(B) is inversely proportional to the distance from the edge (in addition to any other connectivity constraints you want to impose, there's normally a connectedness one, and there will certainly be a likelihood term for the pixel's intensity). The advantage of doing this is that if you can express everything as a probability model, you don't need to rely on heuristics and you can use standard mechanisms for performing inference.

The downside is you need a fairly strong mathematical background to attempt this; I don't know what the scale of the project you're proposing is, but if you want results quickly or you're lacking the necessary background this is going to be pretty daunting.